# Nexus: Getting connection timed out while uploading file into getting

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, nexus3

Getting an error which uploading .tgz file into nexus using jenkins pipeline script.

[image]

> Stage using in my pipeline script as

stage('Upload tar file into nexus') {
            steps {
                sh """
                    curl -f -v $NEXUS --upload-file partnerPortal-* http://localhost:8080/repository/partnerFrontEnd-test/partnerPortal-`date +"%d-%m-%Y-%H.%M"`.tgz
                """
            }
        }

Note: I'm having jenkins and nexus on the same server. My hosts file is having 127.0.0.1 localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding -u to the curl command, resolved my issue.

curl -f -v **-u** $NEXUS --upload-file customerPortal-* https://localhost:8081/-`date +"%d-%m-%Y-%H.%M"`.tar.gz